# When we should use "freak out" & when "afraid"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

What is the difference between *freak out* and *afraid*? When should we use *freak out* and when *afraid*?

*OED* definition for *freak out*:

> (occas. without out):
>
> to undergo an intense emotional experience, to become > stimulated, to rave, esp. under the influence of hallucinatory drugs. Also trans., to cause (a person) to be aroused or stimulated in such a way. (Also in more trivial uses.)

*OED* definition for *afraid*:

> *adj.* Chiefly predicative.
>
> 1. Alarmed, frightened; in a state of fear or apprehension, moved or actuated by fear.

Comment: Freaking out is slang for being extremely afraid. It is not a matter of when you use it but to whom you say it

Comment: Which dictionaries have you looked in?

Comment: Be afraid on the dance floor: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVZh4WcdC3s

Answer (score 1):

The OED defines *freak out* as:

> to undergo an intense emotional experience, to become stimulated, to
>   rave, especially under the influence of hallucinatory drugs. Also
>   transitive, to cause (a person) to be aroused or stimulated in such a
>   way.

It is probably best avoided in formal prose.

*To be afraid* describes an emotional reaction to something perceived as dangerous and thus causing a state of fear.

Comment: I am 100% sure you can freak out when someone is stalking you. I agree (as per my comment) that it is slang

Answer (score 0):

If you are afraid, you are feeling fear. If you are freaking out, you are having an intense stress reaction to fear, which may (though not necessarily) include physical manifestations such as perspiration, dilated pupils, or screaming. As Barrie England says, "freak out" may not be an appropriate term to use in formal settings.

Answer (score 0):

Freaking out will generally have an obvious physical response, such as throwing up your hands, sudden sharp screaming, etc.

Being afraid can be a much more quiet and internalised affair.

However, freaking out is becoming more widely used to mean "inside, I feel the way that you would if you were suddenly screaming and throwing up your hands, etc."